# Telling Structure to ignore a URL segment

Tags: structure, ee4, ee5

I'm a little rusty with how Structure handles URL segments, so hopefully someone here can help. I'm using Structure on a site to handle all of the page management. One of the Structure-managed pages has a form on it:

https://www.domain.com/form/

I've code the form so that upon a successful submission, the user should be redirected to another Structure-managed page:

https://www.domain.com/form/thanks/

However, the form add-on that I'm using automatically appends another segment to the success URL, like so:

https://www.domain.com/form/thanks/9b67c74423314c9dr04dcx6210032052

That last segment is dynamically generated for each form submission by the form add-on. However, as far as Structure is concerned, that additional URL segment is a non-existent page and so it returns a 404.

Is there a way to "trick" Structure into basically ignoring that last URL segment altogether and instead, just displaying https://www.domain.com/form/thanks/?

The site in question is using EE4 (and will be upgraded to EE5 soon) and Structure v4.4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at freebie: https://addons.reinos.nl/freebie
set it to ignore all segments after "thanks"

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that add-on. It did the trick.